# python/opencv: how to identify a cycle with points on the images given?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I have a sequence of images of the heart arteries. Scanning through the images fast, could see the pattern on how the artery moves when the heart beats. On each image, the same junction point is detected and one can analyze the motion of the junction point.

I have an array, storing the coordinates of the detected junction point in each of the images. From these coordinates, I want to find out the motion of the artery so as to be able to identify when is the start of a heart beat cycle and when is the end. assuming the heart beats in a eclipse shape. is there any algorithm out there which i could use to identify the heart beat cycle?  (could use the highest point to help?)

or i have to based on logic and for loops?

Comment: Please provide sample screenshots.

Comment: +1, Please upload a data set somewhere.  I have dealt with similar problems before, would be interested to see what I can do with your data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to be more specific with the algorithm, can you please attach a screen shot.

the only algorithm I have been thinking about is a viola johnes for object detection. 
[enjoy...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework)